# Is there a way to report a job banner if I'm sure it's a fraud?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs

Please note that the question is **not** "how do I know for sure that it's a fraud". I only want to know where to report it. If you're too curious of the details, I'm easily contactable. If you're too lazy to look me up, that's your problem (I mean it in a cocky but politely friendly way).   :)

I called one of the banners just to get a feeling of what the said company was doing a while ago when I was looking for a new job. We got together and spent almost 2 hours talking.

During that time, I recognized a number of warning flags and, of course, backed off politely but firmly. The problem is that if they get their hands on a less experienced, less cynical and more trusting person, they'll probably cause a lot of damage.

I've asked two of my colleagues to do the same. The company tried the exact same tricks on them, as well. As far I know, it's been going on for quite a few months.

Is there a way to downvote a job advert on SO? How?

[image]

Comment: You mean on Careers.SO?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Possibly. I refer to the banners that lie to the right in the GUI.

Comment: If it was in the "Looking for a Job" box, then that is sourced from careers.  If so, this is probably better on MSE.

Comment: How do you know that you've correctly recognized that the company is *evil* and how would they *cause a lot of damage*? Are you sure your vote would be correct?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Please see the edit. It's the red marked area I mean.

Comment: @TLama I've been there myself. I've asked two others to do so. I know a person who was used by them just the way I suspected. I've seen that happen before. So, no, I can't be certain **totally**. But it's waaay too significant warning flags to ignore.

Comment: What's the nature of the fraud that you suspect?

Comment: TBH, I'm not entirely certain what the pipeline for this kind of report is. I've made a mention of it in our internal Careers chat. Somebody from our support team will probably chime in here by Monday at the latest.

Comment: Can you tell us what the "tricks" are? Or maybe go over the conversation? I wouldn't mind knowing.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Good point. I just took a random screenshot. I'll blur those but it doesn't mean it is or isn't any of them. The regarded company's been advertizing for a while now. Just so you know.

Comment: @FunctionR Sure. But not in open forum here because they **might** improve in the future and what's said on the net stays on the net. Forever. My last name is kind of unique so if you're fairly intelligent and know what Facebook and Skype is, you shouldn't have problems getting in touch with me. Also, you can see where I work. Figure out the email yourself, provided that my boss named Donald Duck has the address of **donald.duck@kentor.se**.  :)

Comment: What kind of tricks and what kind of red flags are you talking about? No doubt that there can be a bad company on SO ads, but it would be nice to know your reasoning. Who knows may be you will help others not to fall for a trap.

Comment: @SalvadorDali Please see the comment to FunctionR. We actually already spoke on the phone about it. Anyway, I'm not by myself going to trash a company in open domain like this. I just wanted to know if there was an option to (and need of) controlling ads by the popular vote.

Comment: You haven't told us what the company is so you wouldn't be trashing it.

Comment: @KonradViltersten you just told him that you will not tell anything, because your profile is public. But this does not help in understanding whether the ads is a fraud. Also it is not clear to me why would you care if they can see your profile. If you do not want to work for them, who cares if they will see this post, especially if you are not telling what company are you referring to.

Comment: the suspicious behaviors were what? the warning flags were what? they are frauding people how?

Comment: @KonradViltersten: Why not ask one of your friends if he wants to post here instead?

Comment: What is the point of writing a public post if then you are so secretive?

Comment: @SalvadorDali Common sense and courtesy begs not to discuss such details this openly, at least in my book. The point of the question is where I should report it so that SO can act if they wish. It's **not** my intention to open a potentially infected discussion on "whether it's a fraud", because I already know it is and I'm not curious about what others believe. You might be missing the point of the question - I only want to report it to SO. Not share my findings with all of the community. If you're that curious, do as FunctionR did and contact me.

Comment: @MartinSmith Good point. However, I feel that bitching about all the details and issues in the open is still a sign a lesser person and I feel inconvenient doing so. It might reflect badly on myself in the end, even if the regarded company isn't mentioned by name.

Comment: @chiliNUT Please see my other comments regarding those questions. I understand the curiosity but those need not to be addressed in order to answer my question, which is "where/how to report it". Please note that I'm not looking for evaluation of my claim. I'm rarely wrong in those situations and even if I am, I only wish to notify SO of what I've found out. I'm not looking for approval or vote on the subject. Let others deal with the issue.

Comment: @tmyklebu The point of it being what? Will that affect the answer to "how I report this to SO"? Hardly. Do I need to support my claim on the company before reporting them to SO? Not that I'm aware of. I really prefer not to stimulate the mob mentality. I only wish to let SO know what I've discovered and let them deal with it as they see appropriate.

Comment: @nico Please respect what the **OP is asking** and keep focus on the difference between that and what **you'd like to know**. The public part is "how do I report something to SO regarding job ads". That's the only public part. How I know, isn't public and, as far I can see, doesn't affect the answer to my question. Please explain how it does if I'm wrong and I'll be happy to provide more details. I'm not being secretive. I'm jut not yapping and bitching out all the details that aren't others' concern. You're free to contact me, though.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten I disagree (voiced that with a -1). 1) If you wanna know how to contact Careers SO then you should edit your question by saying only that: "How do I contact Careers SO?". 2) You **are** being secretive for no clear reason (maybe you just want to trash Careers SO for what we know) and this could lead people to think that many of the ads in those banners are fraudulent. 3)There are a "Contact" and a "Legal" links on the page of Careers, it's obvious how to contact them. So, respect **my** right of asking more detail and to think that,as it is, this is a pointless question.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: You expressed concern about the damage the company could do to somebody more naive.  This might not be the only company doing the sketchy things you're worried about.  Point being, a public notice of "hey, these folks are trying to rip you off in the following way" would serve to educate people on how they might be abused.  You're of course free to disclose your findings and opinions as widely or as narrowly as you see fit.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I'll just remove the question...   :)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Check out the contact details on the Careers support page:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/support

You can email your feedback to the email address there (not including it as it may change over time and may be dependent on your geography).

Answer (score 37):

Use the flag feature:

1. Click on the job ad.
2. On the right side menu, click *flag a problem*.
3. Type something in and click *submit*.