# Should I report a company if I know they are lying in their jobs posting

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm not going to name anyone here, but if I know categorically that a company is lying on their [Joel's 12 point score](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/) (i.e. saying they do things that I know they don't), should I report it?

I guess there is no way to prove it either way and it would be up to a candidate to work it out in an interview.

It just feels wrong to me that they are misleading people.

Comment: I guess you could report that, but if you're the only one who did that and have no actual prove, then this might not lead to something. But if these reports increase, then SE should take a look. Thus, I would report it.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283858/is-there-a-way-to-report-a-job-banner-if-im-sure-its-a-fraud and also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332037/so-careers-should-stop-accepting-business-from-predatory-employers

Comment: This is a tough one for SO - if they approach their customer and ask them to prove their 12-point score, will companies generally react in a positive fashion? How much effort are they expected to go to prove their attainment of each point?

Comment: **Who is Joel?**

Comment: If an applicant really cares about those things, then it's in this own interest, to discuss such things. It should be quite obvious then, if they're lying.

Comment: @the4kman [Joel Spolsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky)

Comment: @YohDeadfall Thanks. I feel so out-of-the-loop now.

Comment: @jAC and if, say, they’ve travelled hundreds of miles for the interview...that’s still ok?

Comment: You absolutely should report that to SE and provide whatever info you have. I'm not sure about the specific way/tool/procedure that SE would prefer you to use though. Maybe someone from their stuff could clarify that.

Comment: What if they have changed their internal policies and practises since your last encounter with them?

Comment: @Jeeped I have considered that as a possibility, but it is highly unlikely

Comment: Glassdoor could be the appropriate place to provide such feedback

Comment: the Joel score is based on [this article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/) by @joelspolsky

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I agree that it should be reported to SE, and then based upon any information/evidence they can decide what action should be taken if any. Bringing it to the right people's attention is really all you can do, but should still scratch the "I need to tell someone" itch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always report a listing if you feel the information isn't accurate. The best we can do in this particular case is to let the customer know that their listing was flagged and encourage them to update it if the information is in fact inaccurate. As mentioned, there's no way for us to prove this but we do stress the importance of transparency with the community.